# How to show the first item by default in a dynamic Antd form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

This is probably an easy one for someone. In AntD's forms documentation and demo [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item), their demo starts with no fields. You have to click the "+ Add Field" button for the dynamic form to add and show the first field as shown here..

[image]

If I want it to start out by showing the first field without having to first click the "+ Add Field" button, how is that done? Seems like I'd need to somehow call the add function upon render? Anyways I'm looking for it to show the first passenger when it initially loads the form such as in this screenshot after i've pressed the Add Field button..

[image]

Put another way, I want there always to be a minimum of 1 passenger.

Their demo's code can be viewed in the link above that takes you right to their documentation but here it is as well:

```
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 4 },
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 20 },
  },
};
const formItemLayoutWithOutLabel = {
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 24, offset: 0 },
    sm: { span: 20, offset: 4 },
  },
};

const DynamicFieldSet = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_item" {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel} onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.List name="names">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Form.Item
                  {...(index === 0 ? formItemLayout : formItemLayoutWithOutLabel)}
                  label={index === 0 ? 'Passengers' : ''}
                  required={false}
                  key={field.key}
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    validateTrigger={['onChange', 'onBlur']}
                    rules={[
                      {
                        required: true,
                        whitespace: true,
                        message: "Please input passenger's name or delete this field.",
                      },
                    ]}
                    noStyle
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="passenger name" style={{ width: '60%' }} />
                  </Form.Item>
                  {fields.length > 1 ? (
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      className="dynamic-delete-button"
                      style={{ margin: '0 8px' }}
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </Form.Item>
              ))}
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  style={{ width: '60%' }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicFieldSet />, mountNode);
.dynamic-delete-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #999;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.dynamic-delete-button:hover {
  color: #777;
}
.dynamic-delete-button[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `initialValues` prop. take look at this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-form-item-ant-design-demo-qm1d8

Comment: Ah interesting so when used at the Form tag it essentially accomplishes that. I was using it in a Form.Item tag for another purpose (to make sure one of my non required fields isn't null) but that didn't have the same effect. Very useful!

Answer (score 4):

If you set `initialValues` for Form component as @HamidSarani pointed, it will automatically add needed number of fields. Just, don't put an empty string, like in his example, because you'll not have placeholder shown. Set it as `undefined` instead. That way, placeholder will be displayed as well.

```
<Form initalValues={{names: [undefined]}}>
```